# Going to result after search with SearchDelegate (buildResults)

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a simple search bar with SearchDelegate.

Although there are many resources on the internet about searching, there is almost no source on how to get results when the search is over.

[My list, detail page and search bar are in this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyXPb.gif)

After searching, how can I go to the detail page with the buildResults?

```
class SearchTeam extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    // How can I go to the detail page of the found team name?

  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? [" "]
        : MyData.TEAM_NAME.where((p) => p.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();


    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: (){},

        title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't take advantage of the keyboard's `onSubmitted` event when using a `SearchDelegate` as it won't expose the API to do that. Don't use `SearchDelegate` just for showing the `TextField` in that case. If you want to use your custom page for displaying search results, create your own search input `TextField` as well. It will be easier for you to do that with much better APIs that you can have control over.

If you are to use `SearchDelegate` you have to build your result widget directly in the `buildResults` method. In your case, show a widget using the `query` field which on pressing will take the user to the detail page. Or you can just navigate to the detail page upon pressing the item in the suggested list.

It would be something like this.

```dart
List<String> getResults(String query) {
  // apply getting results logic here
  return [];
}

@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  final results = getResults(query);
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        // assuming `DetailsPage` exists
        Navigator.push(context, DetailsPage(results[index]));
      },
      title: Text(results[index]),
    ),
    itemCount: results.length,
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to use SearchDelegate for this question. According to what you said, it was possible to go to the detail page. Can you give an example of what you wrote in the second paragraph with code?

Comment: okay, I edited the answer with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

it works,
just ignore the returning value of buildResults()

thank you.